# Trying to present 2 UIAlertControllers back to back

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, alert, uialertcontroller

I have a `UIAlertController` in which the options are populated from an array and are presented to the user. The user then selects an option from the alert. After this, I have a separate alert that provides the user with a confirmation message that has an okay button.

```
myAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: item, style: .Default, handler: { 
    (UIAlertAction) in
         self.chosenBusiness.append(businessNameData[item]!)
}))
self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The code above gathers the data from the array and pushes it into actions in myAlert. The code above is inside of a for loop.

After this I use a function to retrieve the topmost view controller, and then push the next alert.

```
let top = topMostController()
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Location pinned", message: "You've successfully pinned this location, good work!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { 
    (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
    print("OK")
}
alertController.addAction(okAction)

self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
top.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: {
     _ in
})
```

The error I receive is:

> Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is
>   deallocating and is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior.
>   UIAlertController: 0x1535b1cd0.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Why are you calling `self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)` in the second block of code? Didn't you already present the first alert in the first block of code.  Also, can you use the completion block of the first alert to display the second (conditionally based on some user action)?

Comment: You can call the presentation of your confirmation AlertController within the action handler for the original AlertController. There is no need to run it on the top-most controller. Just run it on self, as you did for the original. Additionally, you have a retain cycle in your action closure. You need to capture self as [unowned self] or [weak self] to prevent the implicit strong retain in a closure.

Comment: Well I moved self.presentViewController for myAlert but that doesn't impact it. SArnab, could you elaborate a lil more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. The second must be called with the dismissal action of the first. Also, anytime you work with UI, It is safer to use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 
\\code }`

than not if you are not positive you are currently on the main queue.

```
let firstAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "First", message: "This is the first message.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

let secondAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Second", message: "This is the second message.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
let secondDismissAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, completion: nil)
secondAlertController.addAction(secondDismissAction)

let firstDismissAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
    UIAlertAction in
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.presentViewController(secondAlertController, animated: true, handler: nil)
    }
}

firstAlertController.addAction(firstDismissAction)
self.presentViewController(firstAlertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Sethmr, I have used dispatch_async for populating the alert actions for myAlert as I'm pushing those from an array. However I'm lost on what you mean by using the dispatch_async for both of the alertcontrollers

Comment: I just tested the function I wrote. If you just replace the text in mine with the text in yours, it will run. You would only use the dispatch_async for the presentingViewController line, and only on the ones that you might not be on the main queue. For my purposes, I placed my function in viewDidLoad which runs on the main queue unless you call an async function with a completion handler closure, so I only placed it inside the firstDismissAction.

Comment: The second alertController must be called like within the dismissal action of the first alert controller.